# The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics'

Tags: c#, .net, codedom, system.diagnostics

This error makes absolutely no sense to me.
I'm using CodeDOM to compile an executable.
Here's  my class for compiling:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

class Compiler
{
    public static bool Compile(string[] sources, string output, params 
string[] references)
    {
        var results = CompileCsharpSource(sources, "result.exe");
        if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
            return true;
        else
    {
        foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            Console.WriteLine(error.Line + ": " + error.ErrorText);
    }
    return false;
}

    private static CompilerResults CompileCsharpSource(string[] sources, 
string output, params string[] references)
    {
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(references, output);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider())
            return provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, sources);
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm compiling my source:

```
Compiler.Compile(srcList, "test.exe", new string[] { "System.dll", "System.Core.dll", "mscorlib.dll" });
```

And here's the part of the source code I'm compiling where the error occurs:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process p;
if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever").Length > 0) 
  p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever")[0]; 
else 
  return false;
```

So I'm referencing System.dll when compiling, and I'm writing System.Diagnostics in front of process, (I tried using System.Diagnostics too but I produced a similar and less specific error), and for some reason I'm getting this error. I'd appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the references to `CompileCsharpSource`.

Change `Compile` to this:

```
public static bool Compile(string[] sources, string output, params string[] references)
{
    var results = CompileCsharpSource(sources, "result.exe", references);
    if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
            return true;
    else
    {
        foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
            Console.WriteLine(error.Line + ": " + error.ErrorText);
    }
    return false;
}
```